# How do we get more people to our site?

Tags: discussion, chat-sessions

In the **[first brainstorming session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6697/anime-and-manga?tab=conversations)**, we've discussed **[the site's member recruitment model](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/member-recruitment-brainstorming-session-2013-01-30)**

We have decided to take the following steps:

1. Make a list of 5-10 series which would interest an audience of experts in anime/manga. **[Logan M](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/24/logan-m)** and **[Mystical](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/17/mysticial)** are on it.
2. Seed the sites with good, high quality questions on those shows. **Leave some of them unanswered to attract experts with an answer.**
3. Post links to most voted and strongest questions on Reddit, IRC and possibly on 4chan/a/.

We will continue to track the progress of the recruitment state, and will present it in later sessions.

Comment: Note that we currently haven't started anything yet. We're still solidifying a few of the rules and seeding questions before we proceed.

Comment: I think that *actively* leaving questions unanaswered is not going to influence or help the cause. As long as you ask good questions, people will answer anyway (besides the fact that encouraging not to answer is not really what you want to do).

Answer (score 6):

<s>Spam</s> Spread our site is certainly the best way. There are many ways (I'll be making a detailed post for everybody to benefit from):

- Share questions in your FB, Twitter, G+, etc accounts. In order to do this, click the <kbd>share</kbd> button below each question.

  [image]

  Now you can click the buttons and a pop-up will help you share the link. Or you can just copy the link and paste it wherever you need it.
- When participating in other forums you can, when possible, mention the site.
- Share a link to the site in your own SE profile bio.

Can't think of more things to do, but this should a good start.

Comment: In the vein of G+, there is [a Google+ anime community with over 30,000 members](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/107398296600629207634); anyone who joins that could post interesting questions and answers to it to help spread the word.

Answer (score 4):

[Creating community ads for the other sites would be an excellent way of promoting our site within the Stack Exchange Network.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/community-promotion-ads-2013?cb=1) We probably won't want to advertise on all of the sites, but creating an ad on SFF seems like a good idea, and I believe Arqade would be another good site to target with an ad.

Comment: Along with JLU.

Comment: @JNat JLU can't host ads, it's a Beta site like us.

Comment: While we're at it, [I made an ad and published it on SciFi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2535/2217). :)

Comment: I made another ad with Itachi. [One has birds](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2539/2217) and [the other ones doesn't](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2538/2217). I was unsure of which one to propose, so I proposed both. Feel free to vote them. I'm curious to see which one wins. lol

Comment: I've created a [meta post about this](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/364/community-promotion-ads-on-the-se-network).

Answer (score 3):

#### First and foremost:

*anyone with a blog or a forum system should definitely spare a line or two and spread the site*. That is the best way, because it gives good SEO links, and has a very accurate audience reception.

#### Also

- Find friends of yours who are interested and invite them over (I've gotten 3 users that way already).
- When answering questions in anime/manga forums, post links to similar answers you've wrote/read on this site. **[You get badges for it too!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/how-do-i-share-a-link-for-the-new-badges)**
- Post to Facebook/Google+. Maybe friends, or friends of friends are interested and will follow your link!
- Check in your favorite chat rooms (on SE or IRC, whatever), and tell them all about it!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend keeping an eye on questions on SFF.se, movies.se, and possible japanese.se an ensure that those who ask anime/manga questions are made aware of the existence of this site.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of quality, I personally find Naruto, Bleach, DBZ, and even One Piece questions rather trying. There are about 3 million sites out there which cater to these anime. While it's impossible to clamp down on questions from these titles, what can be improved is the signal-to-noise ratio: ask more questions on other titles and ensure that they get comprehensive answers.

Comment: I don't agree with Naruto, Bleach, DBZ, OP = noise and other titles = signal. We want people to come to *our* site. They are free to visit the 3 million other sites but we are not concerned with that.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai Why would they come here when a host of dedicated sites exist elsewhere? Sites which cater to titles like, say, GITS, Baccano, Nodame Cantabile, etc., are rarer and consequently, posing and answering questions on them will draw their traffic. This question is about drawing more traffic, and traffic that will stick around.

Comment: I am not opposed to posting questions on other titles. However, there is no reason to *assume* that people searching for popular titles would not come here. If the content here makes to the first page of search engines, people would definitely come here even searching for the popular titles. Most of the top "other" sites are forums, which caters to a specific demographic. People looking for reliable content would prefer coming here than going through fan theory sites, provided we maintain this place properly, through voting the good content up.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai Er, and that's what I'm saying: there is no content here to do so. It's mainly sharingan after bankai after sharingan, ad nauseum. I don't share your confidence on the quality or reliability of most of the answers either.

Answer (score -4):

I've managed to get more reputation here than almost any other Stack Exchange, but I still have a hard time think of any kind of question that would be a good fit.

I like the idea of an anime stack exchange, but most of the questions I would want to ask are discussion or opinion based, not objective.  I see a lot of on hold topics, and in reading some other meta posts, I see that list topics and recommendations seem to have gone away, with the example questions deleted.

So... I'm a member of this Stack Exchange thinking "What can I do with it?"

Comment: Discussions are not welcome on the main part of the site. There's a [special place for that called chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-). Jump in and let's discuss some possibilities.